# MySQL inner join only select 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (sampleTable) of website access dates as year-month-day, timestamps as year-month-day hour-minutes-seconds, user ids and website access ids. I want to select the access ids which correspond to the first access that occurred on the most recent day. So far I have attempted this with

```
select userID, MAX(dayAccessed) as latestDay from sampleTable group by userID;
```

which returns the most recent day. I then have used this in a inner join to rejoin this query with the original table which orders the columns correctly. My problem is that I cannot access the earliest access id on the most recent day for both user ids as

```
SELECT sampleTable.dayTimeAccessed, sampleTable.userID, latest.latestDay 
FROM 
    (SELECT userID, MAX(dayTimeAccessed) AS latestDay 
    from sampleTable 
    group by userID) AS latest 
INNER JOIN sampleTable 
ON sampleTable.userID = latest.userID AND 
    sampleTable.dayTimeAccessed 
limit 1;
```

only returns one field with the first userID matched.

Comment: Please add sample input data for the `test1` table, and then show us the expected output.  It is not clear what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the MAX date first and then the MIN timestamp:

```
SELECT 
   min(sampleTable.dayTimeAccessed) -- min timestamp per user for the MAX date
  ,latest.userID
  ,latest.latestDay 
FROM 
  ( SELECT userID, MAX(dayAccessed) AS latestDay  -- max date per user
    from sampleTable 
    group by userID
  ) AS latest 
INNER JOIN sampleTable 
ON sampleTable.userID = latest.userID
AND sampleTable.dayAccessed = latest.latestDay
GROUP BY latest.userID, latest.latestDay
```

For MySQL 8 you can use a ROW_NUMBER:

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (
   SELECT *, 
      ROW_NUBMER() -- min timestamp per user for the MAX date
      OVER (PARTITION BY userID
            ORDER BY dayAccessed DESC, dayTimeAccessed ASC) AS rn
   FROM sampleTable
 ) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```